# Does git stash pop get back just the last stash?

Tags: git

I'm using Git and trying to pull from the remote repo.

When I do it's aborted and says it will overwrite something.

If I do `git stash`, then `git pull` and then do `git stash pop` will it just pop only the last things stashed.

If I do the stash pop will I get conflicts.

Comment: As a sidenote, you might want to prefer `git stash apply` to `git stash pop` on a case where you suspect possible conflicts. Because if you try a conflict resolution but it goes awry, hard resetting will leave you with an empty stash, while `apply` would have kept the entry in the stash. Then, **after** conflict resolution is done and all is okay, it's safe to manually `drop` it.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Yes, `git stash pop` will apply the latest stash. See [the git stash pop documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt) for details

Comment: @RomainValeri AFAIK `stash pop` doesn't remove from the stash list if pop fails due to conflicts.

Comment: @Maroun You're perfectly right, I wonder if it changed along the way or if I've always made this false assumption.

Comment: @RomainValeri: it has always been like this. I recommend splitting `pop` into `apply` + `drop` anyway for two reasons: you can accidentally mis-apply, and, it avoids falling into the assumption that if you did a pop, it's always gone (when in fact it's only gone when Git thinks it worked—which doesn't mean it really worked, just that there were no conflicts). In general I advise not using `git stash` at all: just make a commit. But for some specific cases, or for people who really like it, `git stash` is OK as a quick and dirty temporary thing...

Answer (score 0):

When you don't provide a specific stash, [`stash@{0}` is assumed](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt). So the answer to your question is: Yes, it removes the last stashed state from the list and applies it on top of your current working tree state.

Note, however, that if you have conflicts, the stash **isn't** removed from the list, and you'll have to manually remove it by `drop` once the conflicts are resolved:

> Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call `git stash drop` manually afterwards.